# Why can I only share one of my two monitors in Google Meet, but not the other one?

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-monitors, windows-11, 4k-resolution, google-meet

I have two monitors, both 4K, running at 200% font size.

When using Google Meet, I can opt to share my screen, but I can only share one of them, the other doesn't appear as a choice when selecting screens.

Additionally, my primary monitor is not the one I can share. This used to work a while ago and I have yet to find anything in particular to tweak to get this option back.

Anyone know what I can look into?

This is latest Google Chrome on latest Windows 11.

Comment: Start by searching for the system requirements or alike information in https://support.google.com/meet.

Comment: Here is the article: [Requirements for using Google Meet](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/7317473?hl=en). Add more details about the monitor connections to your computer. As this looks as a troubleshooting like question, moving it to [su].

Comment: Meet can't share a monitor if HDR is activated on it. If this is your case, disable HDR on the second monitor. See also the extension [Split Screen for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/split-screen-for-google-c/dnollkdkikklpdganoecjcmmlddbennb).

Comment: @harrymc This is the answer, my primary monitor has HDR enabled, disabled it and I can now share both. If you would care to leave that as a full answer, I will accept it. And I just found out I can use Win+Alt+B to enable/disable HDR, so then this is no longer an issue. Nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meet can't share a monitor if HDR is activated on it.

After the poster has disabled HDR on his second monitor,
he reported being able to share both monitors.

Comment: Also, for future visitors, hitting Win+Alt+B (with Microsoft Game Bar activated) you can quickly enable and disable HDR. This also works while the meeting is underway, and Google Meet will immediately be able to share the screen that had HDR enabled previously.